# How prevent virtualbox to create useless network interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

i'm on an ubuntu based distro (linux lite) and every time i use virtual box it will create many useless connections and they will removed on next boot.
how can i prevent virtualbox to create these conections?

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: em1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:ca:3a:c9:6e:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vboxnet10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vboxnet11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: vboxnet12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: vboxnet13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

Start up VirtualBox GUI and click on `File/Host network manager`.

On the appearing window you can remove these networks one-by-one selecting them and clicking on Remove icon.

**OR**

Use cli to remove these interfaces:

```
$ vboxmanage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0 
$ vboxmanage hostonlyif remove vboxnet1
...
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but in this way i must manually remove all the network interfaces how can do this work automatically . also why virtual box create these interfaces? why it doesn't remove them after it works done?

Comment: Why would you remove it again once you have removed already? VirtualBox will not recreate these on its own.